# NetworkAgentInfo [Ethernet () - 100] validation failed - on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

```
2018-11-12 13:30:56.535 1976-2525/system_process D/ConnectivityService: NetworkAgentInfo [Ethernet () - 100] validation failed
2018-11-12 13:30:58.392 3015-3707/com.google.android.gms E/ChromeSync: [Sync,SyncIntentOperation] Error handling the intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:tv.lattelecom.androidtv flg=0x4000010 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService (has extras) }.
2018-11-12 13:30:59.287 3789-3831/tv.lattelecom.androidtv E/Fabric: Settings request failed.
2018-11-12 13:30:59.288 3789-3830/tv.lattelecom.androidtv E/Answers: Failed to retrieve settings
2018-11-12 13:30:59.291 3789-3832/tv.lattelecom.androidtv W/CrashlyticsCore: Received null settings, skipping report submission!
2018-11-12 13:31:04.737 2828-3872/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2018-11-12 13:31:08.149 2828-3061/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/NetworkScheduler: Invalid component specified.
2018-11-12 13:31:09.227 3789-3826/xxx D/Networking: Executing request: https://...
2018-11-12 13:31:09.228 3789-3826/xxx I/System.out: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "xxxx": No address associated with hostname
2018-11-12 13:31:13.551 1976-2632/system_process D/SntpClient: request time failed: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "2.android.pool.ntp.org": No address associated with hostname
2018-11-12 13:31:28.518 3015-3252/com.google.android.gms E/CheckinRequestProcessor: CheckinNowTaskTag : Checkin failed: https://android.clients.google.com/checkin (fragment #0): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "android.clients.google.com": No address associated with hostname
2018-11-12 13:31:28.522 3015-3252/com.google.android.gms I/CheckinChimeraService: Checkin result code: 0 will be retried.
2018-11-12 13:31:28.543 2828-3408/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/NetworkScheduler: Invalid component specified.
```

Well, I have a connection, but somehow, I see this in my logs. The link for data I'm requesting is good (I get the response), but on emulator it somehow says `UnknownHostException`.